# Случайный выбор строки из таблицы SQL

Tags: java

Скажите, пожалуйста, как случайным образом выбирать строку из бд?
Вот то, что  я сделал

```
ResultSet r1 = 
   (ResultSet) s1.executeQuery(select str from slovar where length(str) > 12);
ResultSet r2 = (ResultSet) s1.executeQuery(select count( * ) from slovar);
int kol = 0;
while (r1.next()) {
    kol = r2.next();
}
int randomStr = (int) Math.random() * kol + 1;
```

И как мне теперь выбрать из r1 строку с номером randomStr?

Comment: @qwas13, Отредактируйте Ваш код. Сейчас он не читаем.

Comment: where id=randomStr

Comment: в таблице я не прописывал сам id

Comment: Эх молодо-зелено: поди и не знает вьюношь, что в SQL таблице нет понятия номера строки...

Answer (score 2):

Наверное проще всего узнать количество строк в результате выполнив

```
r2 = s1.executeQuery("select count( * ) from slovar where length(str) > 12");
```

почти как у Вас и вычислить номер случайной строки (randomStr), как Вы и делаете, а затем ограничить размер выдаваемого результата

ResultSet r1 = (ResultSet) s1.executeQuery(" select str from slovar where length(str) > 12");
s1.setMaxRows(randomStr);

потом читать и в конце у Вас получится искомая строка

```
String str;
while (r1.next)
    str = r1.getString("str");
r1.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться таким запросом:

```
select str from (select str, rownum as order_number from slovar where length(str) > 12)) where order_number
= randomStr
```